# How to get data from JSON after decoding

Tags: php, json

I am trying to get data from a JSON that's a bit complex for me.

How can I get the value in Amount or Transaction date

I can get the MerchantRequestID using this code

```
$mpesaResponse = file_get_contents('php://input');
$jsonMpesaResponse = json_decode($mpesaResponse, true); 
$MerchantRequestID = $jsonMpesaResponse["Body"]["stkCallback"]["MerchantRequestID"];

// An accepted request
{
  "Body":{
    "stkCallback":{
      "MerchantRequestID":"19465-780693-1",
      "CheckoutRequestID":"ws_CO_27072017154747416",
      "ResultCode":0,
      "ResultDesc":"The service request is processed successfully.",
      "CallbackMetadata":{
        "Item":[
          {
            "Name":"Amount",
            "Value":1
          },
          {
            "Name":"MpesaReceiptNumber",
            "Value":"LGR7OWQX0R"
          },
          {
            "Name":"Balance"
          },
          {
            "Name":"TransactionDate",
            "Value":20170727154800
          },
          {
            "Name":"PhoneNumber",
            "Value":254721566839
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

At the moment it comes out blank what ever i try

Comment: how do you decode ? your are using an 'array' strategy, but we cant see whether you decoded to an array of a stdClass

Comment: iv updated the code as I had used the wrong one.please have a look and advise

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through your `Item` array.

```
<?php

$str = '
{
  "Body":{
    "stkCallback":{
      "MerchantRequestID":"19465-780693-1",
      "CheckoutRequestID":"ws_CO_27072017154747416",
      "ResultCode":0,
      "ResultDesc":"The service request is processed successfully.",
      "CallbackMetadata":{
        "Item":[
          {
            "Name":"Amount",
            "Value":1
          },
          {
            "Name":"MpesaReceiptNumber",
            "Value":"LGR7OWQX0R"
          },
          {
            "Name":"Balance"
          },
          {
            "Name":"TransactionDate",
            "Value":20170727154800
          },
          {
            "Name":"PhoneNumber",
            "Value":254721566839
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
';

$json = json_decode($str, true);

foreach($json['Body']['stkCallback']['CallbackMetadata']['Item'] as $index => $item_array_element){

    if( $item_array_element['Name'] == 'Amount' ){
        echo "Found Amount " . $item_array_element['Value'] . "\n";
    }
    else if( $item_array_element['Name'] == 'TransactionDate' ){
        echo "Found TransactionDate " . $item_array_element['Value'] . "\n";
    }

}
```

Output

```
Found Amount 1
Found TransactionDate 20170727154800
```